# Number theory question - squares

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Suppose I have $n,m,t$ positive integers such as $nm$ is a square and $mt$ is a square, how do I prove that $nt$ is also a square?

I have said: $nm=k^2$, $mt=f^2$ so $nt=(kf)^2/m^2=(kf/m)^2$. I need to prove that $kf/m$ is integer. I have said that $m|f^2$, so there are several options - if $m=1$ we are done, if $m|f$ then we are also done. we are left with $m|f^2$, but not $f$. similarly goes for $m|k^2$, and here I am stuck.

Thanks very Much

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I think that the question is very well-phrased, and very accurate.

Comment: Hello mike: that is not the issue. This is not a website where people do your homework for you. You should indicate what you have tried, where you are stuck, etc., so that people can *help* you.

Comment: I have said:
nm=k^2
mt=f^2
so
nt=(kf)^2/m^2=(kf/m)^2
I need to prove that kf/m is integer. I have said that m|f^2, so there are several options - if m=1 we are done, if m|f then we are also done. we are left with m|f^2, but not f. similarly goes for m|k^2, and here I am stuck.

Comment: Fantastic. I have edited that into your question.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: Perhaps the illustratory example in the site tour should be modified. It seems no more detailed than the OP's question. It is "Why is $\left(1+\frac{2\ln3}{3}\right)^{-3/2}\leq\frac{2}{3}$ trivial ?" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(nm)(mt)$ is a perfect square. That is, $(nt)m^2$ is a perfect square. So $nt$ must be a perfect square.

Are you perhaps in need of a lemma that if $A$ is a perfect square and $AB$ is a perfect square, then $B$ is a perfect square? This is pretty easy to show if you use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique factorization into prime powers.)

Answer (score 0):

The rational root $\,kf/m\,$ of $\, x^2\!-nt\,$ is an integer by the [Rational Root Test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) Thus $\,nt\,$ is a square.